# xbindkeys + xmacroplay are terribly slow on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, remapping, xbindkeys

I've been using a combination of `xbindkeys` and `xmacroplay` to set up a new keyboard layer activated with the Windows key.

Here's a sample:

```
#Up
"echo 'KeyStrRelease Super_L KeyStrRelease i KeyStr Up KeyStrPress Super_L' | xmacroplay :0"
    Mod4 + i
```

It used to work perfectly on Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa (based on Ubuntu 16.04 Trusty).

When I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic and copied my `.xbindkeysrc` config over, I've discovered that it now works terribly slow.

Each keypress now takes about 1 second to complete.

Even worse, keypresses pile up. For example, I press Win+Shift+J (which emulates Shift+Left) *five times* to select five characters of text. For several seconds nothing happens, the caret not blinking, then all five characters appear selected at once.

Why? How do make it instant?

PS I tried running `xbindkeys` and `xmacroplay` separately and I haven't noticed a delay.
PPS Tried `nice -n-20`, no luck.

Comment: I've migrated back to Mint. xbindkeys + xmacroplay are now fast again. The delay is still noticeable but on Mint it isn't longer than time between two keypresses.